# Why is iodine added to salt? As opposed to fluor or fats/oils like iron and vitamin A?

Tags: biochemistry, food, health, food-chemistry

Is there a particular reason why certain foods are enriched or fortified with certain nutrients?  Such as salt with iodine?  Or did we just get used to doing things a certain way since we started enriching foods about a century ago?

Comment: Where I live, supermarkets offer cooking salt enriched with iodates **and** fluorides. "Food grade salt shall be used when salt is used as a carrier for food additives or nutrients for technological or public health reasons. Examples of such preparations are mixtures of salt with nitrate and/or nitrite (curing salt) and salt mixed with small
amounts of fluoride, iodide or iodate, iron, vitamins, etc., and additives used to carry or stabilize such additions." [(FAO, 1985)](https://agris.fao.org/agris-search/search.do?recordID=XF9764821)

Comment: Please demonstrate the research you have put into this question (which is to do with health policy, rather than biology) yourself. Did you look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodised_salt) on this topic, for example?